# How to document enum class values out of line in source with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to document an `enum class` values out of line in the *.cpp file:

Consider:

```
class SomeClass
{
    enum class MyEnum
    {
        val1
    };
};
```

and out-of-line Doxygen documentation in the *.cpp file:

```
/*!
 * \class SomeClass
 * ...
 *\

/*!
 * \enum SomeClass:MyEnum
 * This works fine.
 */

/*!
 * \var SomeClass::MyEnum::val1
 * And this does not...
 */
```

The third comment section fails with this message:

```
warning: no matching class member found for SomeClass::MyEnum::val1
```

I have tried many variations suggested in other similar questions and answers but to no avail. I can either make the `enum class` a regular `enum` or put the documentation inline to the header. Any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
class SomeClass
{
    enum class MyEnum
    {
        val1
    };
};
```

and in the cpp file:

```
/*!
 * \class SomeClass
 * ...
 */

/*!
 * \enum SomeClass:MyEnum
 * This works fine.
 */

/*!
 * \var SomeClass::val1
 * And this works now, too...
 */
```

Note that I removed the tag name of the enumeration.

Comment: Thanks, I mention that option in OP. It works with regular `enums` but not with `enum class`. Anyway, I have abandoned Doxygen and moved to `QDoc` as I use Qt primarily.

Comment: Oh, I tried exactly the code I posted, and it worked for me even with `enum class`.

Comment: Interesting, you are right. That is not very intuitive and will not work for multiple `enum class`es with the same values but it is the answer for current Doxygen.